# Displaying Google Play Achievements

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have made a game, and when playing it the achievements show as a pop up in game when awarded.  And it appears to be working correctly, they're iterating when they're meant to, they're being awarded for completing set tasks as they're meant to.  But on the screen in "Play Games", it doesn't display them, and when you click on an achievement in the pop up, it doesn't let you view them.

Like so:

[image: My Hangman game]

I want it to appear like:

[image]

What am I missing?  I've looked all over the developer console and can't find anything to make this change.

Comment: I went through this with my own game, after googling a lot I found out that  a lot of people mention that there are some threshold number of players who should unlock achievements before this tab will be visible. Although I haven't seen any proof from Google. 

As for my game, the tab appeared approximately after a mouth since publishing them and more than 10k achievement unlocks.

Comment: @alexeygorovoy it's not this. I have since made another game and that works perfectly. Can't see any differences in the 2. I've got another question open for it.

Answer (score 0):

From the Google Play Games Service [documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/achievements), Make sure that you follow the instruction here that to show a player's achievements, call [`getAchievementsIntent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/achievement/Achievements.html#getAchievementsIntent(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)) to get an [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) to create the default achievements UI. Your game can then bring up the UI by calling [`startActivityForResult`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,int))

```
startActivityForResult(Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(mGoogleApiClient),
        REQUEST_ACHIEVEMENTS);
```

In the following snippet, `REQUEST_ACHIEVEMENTS` is an arbitrary integer used as the request code.

Also from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34409334/how-to-show-the-google-play-game-achievements), make sure you publish the game in the developer console, to see the achievements in the activity

If this options adidn't work on you, then maybe [AlexeyGorovoy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1178797/alexeygorovoy) is correct.

Comment: I believe this is for bringing a window up within the app to display the achievements, not to display them on the Play Games app.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen because you haven't publish your game in **Game Services**.
First publish game in google service which is situated in **Google Play Developer Console**.
Then your achievements tab will be created under your game in **Play Games**.

Comment: The game is published. I've since made another game - Reactions, using the same code and put on play store etc, with a lot less downloads all works perfect.

Comment: how much download your game has?